# SQL connect two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with two columns like

```
column1   column2
01234     56789
33333     883737
```

What I need is something like this, but I've no idea how to sql this:

> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (value1|+|value2)='0123456789'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the CONCAT function, as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE CONCAT(column1, column2) = '0123456789';
```

**Reference**:

[CONCAT function on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CONCAT(value1,value2)='0123456789'

note, you lose the indexing advantages by using this function.
I assumed value1 and value2 are tge column names vs column1 column2.